# Is it a bad practice to Export a CSV doing it in client-side only?

Tags: javascript, architecture, frontend

I have a **report** and I'm mounting this report using my application state data only. I format my data, and display it into a table.

Users should have the option of Downloading this data as CSV. I think creating a New API endpoint for this would be **overkilling**. Then I was thinking about exporting this in client-side, converting the JSON into CSV and sending this as a download to the user.

Is it a bad practice??? Should I use back-end rain or shine?

Answer (score 1):

If the data is exactly the same as the other API endpoint, then I wouldn't create a new endpoint, but just accept and respond to `Content-Type: text/csv` .

However, doing it client side is totally acceptable and something I've done in the past.

**PROS:**

- Reduced server load
- No need to support a different content-type on your endpoint

**CONS:**

- Wouldn't be available if you wanted if some other client wanted it
- Depending on how you generate the csv, if the data changes you might need to update the client code.
- Might be tough to get the [download to work in old browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)